# Add JSON data to datatable

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I want to add JSON data to a existing datatable.

The JSON data looks like this:

```
[
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","X"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","X"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","X"],
    ["Trident","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","X"]
]
```

I tried:

```
$('#' + tab + '_table').dataTable().fnAddData(data);
```

`data` is holding the JSON data.

Anything seems wrong there since it adds only one row with this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're asking dataTables to add raw JSON data to your table. You should parse it first with `JSON.parse()` and add the resulting Javascript array.

```
var jsdata = JSON.parse(data);
$('#' + tab + '_table').dataTable().fnAddData(jsdata);
```

Comment: Okay one more question. How can i remove the existing rows? So that it does not just adds them but removes the old ones before? Thanks

Comment: Use `fnClearTable()` to empty the table completely, or `fnDeleteRow()` to be more selective. Details are in [the API docs](http://datatables.net/api) for DataTables